# Well-defined map on tensor product

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Consider the map $$f:V\otimes V\to \text{Sym}^2(V),\quad x\otimes y\mapsto x\otimes y +y\otimes x.$$ Here $V$ is a $k$ vector space.

Since the elements $x\otimes y$ aren't a basis, I wonder, why this map is well-defined. What do I have to do in order to show this? Does the universal property help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the universal property. Namely, consider the map $B \colon V \times V \rightarrow \operatorname{Sym}^2(V)$ given by $$B(x,y) = x \otimes y + y \otimes x. $$
Since this map is bilinear, the universal property guarantees there exists a unique linear map $f \colon V \otimes V \rightarrow \operatorname{Sym}^2(V)$ such that 
$$f(x \otimes y) = B(x,y) = x \otimes y + y \otimes x $$
 for all $x,y \in V$.